# I can't run start-dfs.sh in my Hadoop Grid5000 cluster (Permission denied)

Tags: hadoop, ssh, hdfs

I can navigate from node to node with an ssh connection without any problems, for example from parasilo-1 to parasilo-10.
`cat ~/.ssh/id_rsa.pub >> ~/.ssh/authorized_keys` doesn't change anything unfortunately.

I am connected in SSH to my master node (parasilo-1) on Grid5000 to run a hdfs command:

```
user@parasilo-1:~$ ./hadoop/hadoop-3.3.4/sbin/start-dfs.sh 
Starting namenodes on [parasilo-1.rennes.grid5000.fr]
parasilo-1.rennes.grid5000.fr: user@parasilo-1.rennes.grid5000.fr: Permission denied (publickey,password).
Starting datanodes
parasilo-1.rennes.grid5000.fr: user@parasilo-1.rennes.grid5000.fr: Permission denied (publickey,password).
parasilo-10.rennes.grid5000.fr: user@parasilo-10.rennes.grid5000.fr: Permission denied (publickey,password).
Starting secondary namenodes [parasilo-1.rennes.grid5000.fr]
parasilo-1.rennes.grid5000.fr: user@parasilo-1.rennes.grid5000.fr: Permission denied (publickey,password).
2023-01-12 15:54:57,462 WARN util.NativeCodeLoader: Unable to load native-hadoop library for your platform... using builtin-java classes where applicable
```

Does anyone have an idea how to make this command run correctly?

Answer (score 0):

You need to `ssh-copy-id` to **all** datanodes, not only edit localhost authorized keys. And there should be no password prompt.

If it's not working, there's no harm in generating a new key and trying again.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. But i don't really understand. I try to share my ssh-key from my remote server, with : ssh-copy-id -i /home/user/.ssh/id_rsa user@parasilo-1.rennes.grid5000.fr

But nothing chang, i have the same issue. I think i don't understand how to copy it to all datanodes, how do you proceed ?

Thanks for your answer.

Comment: Run the exact same command for `user@<other server>`, for every server, not only one of them. You should also be able to SSH between every other node, such as from 2 to 5, and _vice versa_